# Unable to print image and bitmap

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2009

I am trying to print a label (with barcode, text etc.) and an image using Dynamics AX 2009.

The problem is that all is printed except the image!

What can be the problem ? 
Is there some Axapta limitation about images ?

Comment: How are you trying to print the image?  You need to add more detail to your questions.  Is it through code?  Where is your code?

Comment: Ditto to Alex K. 
Ensure that the Ax service account has access to the directory the image file is located (also, is it running from the client or the server?).  You can test this from the windows command prompt using 'runas'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Older versions of AX do not support GIF files, I don't know if it is fixed in AX 2009.

The reports `tutorial_GraphicsCustBalanceList` and `Tutorial_sushiInvoice` demonstrate how to print images.